# Check if Tweet was successful

Tags: twitter

On my website I have placed a tweet button. I want to allow Users to Tweet certain content.
So if a user clicks the Tweet Button and tweets - I want to save the Tweet ID in my database.

How do I get the response from Twitter

1. that the Tweet was successful
2. what the Tweet id is

Sorry, no clue how to do that. Any Tips where to start?

Comment: Your question needs more information. Is tweet button a Twitter widget or html? What programming language are you using? If the button is HTML and you've tried to write code, post a sample of what you tried. Also, tag the question so that people using the same programming language and interested in Twitter will see your question more easily.